# C# - Using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject with JsonConverter[]

Tags: c#, json, json.net, dbnull

I'm having some issues when converting a result row from the DB (`SQL Server`) into `json` format with `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert`.
The issue is, that some columns can contain `DBNull` values. This causes trouble when the item is being converted.
I'm trying to convert the result row this way:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_ResultData);
```

I have seen that there is a parameter `params JsonConverter[] converters` in the `SerializeObject` method. Question 1: Can using this option help me to avoid the crash on a `DBNull` value? Question 2: How to use this function? I actually did not find good examples, which helped me to understand the handling of it.

```
public class JsonConverterUstId : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help. If you need further information, please let me know.

Comment: have you tried jsonProperties? - NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore

Comment: We have done the same sort of thing.  However we just do the JsonConvert.SerializeObhect(dataTable).  without issues.  It seems to handle the nulls fine.

Comment: @JohnnBlade Thanks for the hint. I've added the settings as you proposed, but it still throws an error. Actually I don't understand why it seems ignoring the setting...